# Specify multiple command line parameters

Tags: windows, registry

I am following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by Microsoft to register an application with a web protocol.

By adding this key:
    shell/open/command/(Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"

I am able to pass in a single parameter. How do I pass in many parameters, separated by a delimiter (say a space)? I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
shell/open/command/(Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1" "%2" "%3"
```

Comment: what are those other parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the OS will only pass one parameter: the clicked URL.

If you need more information, perhaps you could encode it in the URL itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try `shell/open/command/(Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1" %*`